# Определение необходимой версии компилятора

Tags: c++, g++

Разрабатывается проект на языке c++, который предполагается использовать на абсолютно разнообразных версиях операционных систем на ядре Linux.

Вопрос прозвучит странно, но есть ли какие-нибудь средства определения необходимой версии компилятора g++ для успешной сборки проекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь находятся описания огромного количества предопределённых макросов: [Pre-defined Compiler Macros](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/), по разделам:

- [Стандарты](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Standards/)
- [Компиляторы](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/) (определяторы версий GCC и примеры для них находятся здесь)
- [Операционные системы](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/)
- и пр, и пр...